# Replace localhost with my domain in Laravel when in production

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am using SPA (Laravel and Vuejs). When in development, website project worked perfect but when after running npm run production and put it on live server, I got errors saying

> Access to Xmlhttprequest at http://localhost:8000/auth_check from origin https://hamariweb.com/auth_check has been blocked by Cors policy.

I have tried different solutions that fixed their problems but not mine. I want to know what is wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an ENV setting in your `.env` file like this.

```
APP_URL=https://hamariweb.com
```

Then share that env file to your javascript code like this.

```
MIX_APP_URL="${APP_URL}"
```

Any ENV settings that start with `MIX_` are passed to Javascript and this is passing it the initial APP URL value.

To finally grab the app url in the JS do this:

```
process.env.MIX_APP_URL
```

You can even assign the entire env settings globally like this.

```js
if(process && process.env){
    window.env          = process.env;
}
```

Any .env MIX_ variables will be available in window.env at that point and in your SPA you'll be able to make the URL or any other variable configurable based on environment.

Comment: Please Vuejs can't read process env value so the problem still remains.

Comment: Bro, the problem disappears when running it on Firefox browser. Any idea why the problem disappear on Firefox browser instead of other browsers?

Comment: You’ll have to restart npm run prod or npm run watch for this to work.

Comment: The problem now solved by removing app.js and running npm run dev again. That solved the problem. Thanks for your productive helps bro.

Comment: Yeah anytime you change your env file to add MIX_ settings to pass to the JS you’ll have to restart npm processes. Be sure to mark my answer as the solution if that did it for ya.

Comment: Yes I have already marked your answer. Your help is greatly appreciated thanks. 

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like somewhere in your code you're trying to send a request to http://localhost:8000/auth_check which isn't going to work in prod.  You need to find the call to that URL and replace it with a call to the correct URL.

Comment: Sir, Can you please guide me to replace it with my domain if you can help?

Comment: I have no idea how your code is structured, so I can't begin telling you where to look.  If you don't know yourself, I recommend talking to the person who wrote the original code.  If that's not an option, you're going to have to go through the code and ctrl+f for http://localhost:8000/auth_check .  And then you still might not find it.  So if that doesn't work, you'll need to figure out where your webserver gets its config from and start taking that apart.  Good luck!

Comment: Okay, I wrote the original code. I created APP_URL that is shared to Vue - i also set it globally - window.env = process.env.MIX_APP_URL. If that case is not solved, then I have to build SPA from scratch. Thanks though.